# GeoServer with SQL server consuming all my CPU

Tags: geoserver, sql-server, sld, tomcat

This question is long please bear me and my problem.
**SQL Server Query profiler**
The **Sample Query** from profiler that GeoServer is running that corresponds to **SLD** I am using and not the **SQL SERVER** view I am using is:

```
SELECT "siteId","Vendor",CAST("SP_GEOMETRY".STSrid as VARCHAR) + ':' 
+ "SP_GEOMETRY".STAsText() as "SP_GEOMETRY" FROM "Data"."sites" 
WHERE ("SP_GEOMETRY".Filter(geometry::STGeomFromText
('POLYGON ((80.12878722280502 28.280198584198256, 
    80.12878722280502 29.559126104578176, 81.58996886322707
 `29.559126104578176, 81.58996886322707 28.280198584198256,
 80.12878722280502 28.280198584198256))', 4326)) = 
1 AND ( UPPER("Vendor") LIKE 'A%'  OR  UPPER("Vendor") LIKE 'B%' ))`
```

I have used JavaScript as suggested by [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23769/prevent-openlayer-wms-layer-cache-by-browser) to redraw pages at 5 minutes interval. It shows 100% CPU utilization when layer is refreshed.
**IF I open multiple pages then page just gets locked.**

[image]

I have Computer with following configuration used for **GeoServer, SQL Server and Apache Tomcat**.   The person who was using it until I demonstrated my project was only me but when I ran this only with 5 person the page just hang(chrome browser) and same thing is happening when I open 5-6 window with same address. I am using GeoServer WMS layer with OpenLayers and Google Maps. The Google map loads very fast but my layer loads very slow 1/2 min. The zooming takes similar time. I have used JAI and all for GeoServer. Database is **indexed and the query takes 0 ms** when I do it from SSMS. The GeoServer is deployed inside Tomcat and data directory is outside the war. I have problem accessing only map pages and believe the memory requirement is more for maps but I am unable to find actual problem.
**SQL Server is actually consuming most of the CPU and Tomcat is consuming most of the memory.**

[image]

The task manager shows following usage:

[image]

The perfmon shows following usage:

[image]

Comment: You may wish to ask this of the GeoServer mailing list - http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Mailing+Lists

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan Did that with the problem I am facing

Comment: Its not recommendable to switch library. But I know an Organization(gov) which used geoserver for large data analysis and rendering. But the web app crashes in their case and they switched to mapserver. If your code base is small try the same performance analysis with mapserver and see the difference.

Comment: @rashad sql tuning had great impact on my case I used sql server tool to capture the sql that geoserver was running and performed tuning which solved the problem i have to say.

Comment: @kinkajou could you post your comment about sql tuning as an answer so this thread does not reappear on the unanswered question list? Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain that is the exact query that is being run, not a similar query with a different bounding box or other filters? Even if the exact query being run is very fast, how much data is being returned? How much rendering is geoserver needing to do? How complicated is the SLD? Typically a query for all the records in a table can start returning data instantly but it can take a long time to actually transfer and render all of those records.

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to geometry format requested from SQL Server. If you allow for SQL Server to provide the native format this will be faster than using WKB generated by SQL server.

A way of avoiding this was introduced in Geoserver 2.3.1. Read the [release documents](http://blog.geoserver.org/2013/04/23/geoserver-2-3-1-released/) for more information.